# What's the most efficient way to dynamically display context-sensitive ads?

Tags: java, adsense

I've got a web platform here which I'd like to monetize via context-sensitive ads.

The decision which ad should be displayed must be based on the correlation between rapidly changing content and relavance of matching ads. Thus, these ads must be found **in real time** (no caching possible!).

I already have a db filled with millions of ads together with keywords that describe these ads.

I also implemented an algorithm which analyizes the content, which is being viewed by the user, which then chooses a matching ad (based on its keywords).

Now, the problem is: Since there are millions of ads available, my algorithm has to step through this big list of ads and check if (and how good) each ad's keywords match to the currently viewed content.

This takes a very long time and has to be redone everytime content changes (which can happen within seconds). Iterating through the list of ads and fetching the keywords alone is already very slow.

---

**Update:** To make it a little clearer, here is a quick code example of what I am doing:

```
String text = getText(); // The content to analyse
text = text.toLowerCase();
List<Ad> ads = getAds();
Ad bestMatchingAd = null;

// ads.length() == Millions!
for (Ad ad : ads){
 List<String> keywords = ad.getKeywords();

 // keywords.length() == ~50
 for (String keyword : keywords){
  keyword = keyword.toLowerCase();
  if (text.indexOf(keyword) != -1){
   ad.increaseHitcounter(); // Increases number of keyword hits by 1
  }
 }

 // Check if this ad fits best to the given text
 if (bestMatchingAd != null){
  if (bestMatchingAd.getHitcounter() < ad.getHitcounter()){
   bestMatchingAd = ad;
  }
 }
 else{
  bestMatchingAd = ad;
 }
}

showAd(bestMatchingAd);
```

---

As you can see, I am iterating over ALL ads and ALL keywords everytime content changes. That's to much and takes way to long. What would be a better solution here?

**Note:** Common solutions like **Adsense** are not an option because the content is not visible to the public. Thus, an own implementation is required.

Comment: you need an index on those ads.

Comment: @DanD. Could you explain that a little more precisely?

Comment: @Synxmax Java with MySql

Comment: Just off the top of my head: You could index the ads in a full-text search engine (e.g Apache Lucene) and use the content to query against it.

Comment: @RoToRa Yeah, but put a index on what? Usually e.g. you'd put an index on a column but in this case ads have multiple keywords so I think I'd be a little difficult to use indexes here.

Comment: I added some code example in my original post to make clearer what I mean.

Comment: @valmar: I'm not speaking of a index in a relational database (such as MySQL, Oracle), but separate full-text search engine. Did you look at Apache Lucene?

Comment: @RoToRa Not yet. I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can make different table in database according to the keyword for example for keyoword starting from "A" there will be table named a_table. now in ur code, u can search for keyword like what keyword is in the contain. put simple if else ladder. it will definitly improve performance as calculation is always faster in programming language than in database.

Comment: Nope, it's they other way round. Check out my code example in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that searching for "best" ads for every rapidly changing webpage. The crucial issue here is real-time. Queries are the keywords from webpage, which change from time to time, while the targets are keywords from ads, which are relative stable.

**My solution:**

1/ Inverted indexes should be generated for all ads in a off-line fashion. You might want to adpot some kind of cloud computing technology like mapreduce if you have a huge number of them.

2/ Whenever a webpage's "content" changes, it is the right time to re-analyze its keywords and match against inverted indexes you have already generated. Taken advantage of inverted indexes, For each ads, it will be finished in a quite short time.

**Two things here are crucial for you now, a) when you judge a webpage really changed , and b) what the best match is.**

for a, some event directely lead to the changing, for example, a user posts a new comments onto the webpage or someone edits his poster.

for b, To count the ads's keywords hits or randomly peak a ads with at least one hit is probably the most simple and effient way. You can make the standard of best match more complicated with the loss of effiency.

That's it. But I really wonder if it is necessary to handle such a real-time issue. Indeed, You can do it, with the cost of computing resource.

Hope it will be useful for you.

Comment: I don't have that much computing power available, so I am looking for a smarter solution. Check out my updated code sample in my original post. Maybe you see potential for optimization.

Comment: @valmar 1> you can simply generate inverted indexes using single ordinary PC. According to your post, ads won't change rapidly as webpage do. Though it is an extremely time-comsuming task, it is an off-line task.You can gain really much better real-time performance than the KMP searching（i.e. text.indexOf()）. 2> you said below codes:"I am iterating over ALL ads and ALL keywords everytime content changes". You did the right thing. DON'T do that at everytime a user require the page.

Comment: Well, I MUST do that everytime the user requires a page because then content changes and I need matching ads.

Comment: @valmar I don't quite understand why you MUST do that everytime user requires page, instead of when some events really lead to the content's change. Does The page's content change everytime user require it? Maybe your case is quite diffirent from others. You can think about it.

Answer (score -1):

you shouldnt be iterating through a list, you need something more efficient for instance a hash key or a binary tree.

i bet you can find lots of information if you search for big o notation and searching algorithms.